# Apache 2.4 + mod_rewrite + FastCGI (php-cgi.exe) on Windows

Tags: windows, mod-rewrite, fastcgi, apache-2.4, php-cgi

I am trying to port my Mac config on Windows for some of my clients.

Since Windows is not Mac OS, I have to use php-cgi.exe instead of PHP-FPM. I have tested each component individually and everything seems to work, so I believe it is a config-only problem.

On my Mac, I have this `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}     ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.dev$
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2/%1/$1" [P]
```

I have added the `RewriteCond` so that you can see where `%1` and `%2` are coming from.

On my Mac it works fine since `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` begins with `/`, but on Windows `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` begins with `C:`.

When testing this config, it produces this error:

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
>
> Reason: DNS lookup failure for: 127.0.0.1:9000c:

It appears (by looking in error.log) that `127.0.0.1:9000:C:` is being considered as a part of an IPv6 address, it is transformed as `[127.0.0.1:9000:C:]` in the log.

If I try to isolate the two parts with `/`:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}     ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.dev$
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2/%1/$1" [P]
                                                     ^
```

I get this error:

> No input file specified.

Actually, I got this error for everything I have tested so far.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Did you tried `RewriteRule ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/%2/%1/$1" [P]` ?